# Why doesn't openSUSE GUI allow one letter usernames during first install?

Tags: linux, system-installation, users, opensuse, useradd

I burned the `openSUSE Tumbleweed` iso on USB and plugged it into a laptop to try it out. I ran the gui installer. When asked to choose a username I typed `q` in the username. However I was unable to proceed. I was met with `The username must be between 2 and 32 characters in length. Try again.` error. I had to add a second letter to pass the step.

However once I finished the install and logged in I could add one letter usernames just like other distros.

```bash
qw@opensuse:~> sudo useradd a
qw@opensuse:~> sudo useradd b
qw@opensuse:~> sudo useradd c
qw@opensuse:~> sudo useradd d
qw@opensuse:~> sudo useradd e
```

I could verify that the users were added by navigating `Settings > Users > Other Users`. If one letter usernames don't cause any issues in the terminal, why does the first installation GUI force usernames to be at least 2 chars long?

Comment: I'll go ahead and argue that it's due to personal preference of the developer.

Comment: Maybe the OS used to require 2 to 32 characters and has since been updated, but the installer hasn't been updated to match. I'd recommend asking the openSUSE devs or looking at the source code to really find out, or maybe filing a bug report about the mismatch.

Comment: The source code in question doesn't give any indication as to why. [Here](https://github.com/yast/yast-users/blob/master/src/lib/y2users/user_validator.rb#L99C38-L99C38)

Comment: @DavidYockey I went ahead and asked this [here](https://github.com/yast/yast-users/pull/297#issuecomment-1635750528), where the current checking was re-introduced into the code base.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Your source code link is interesting. systemd puts some other restrictions on usernames and [this](https://systemd.io/USER_NAMES/) page also talks about limitations imposed by various distributions.